# How exactly Erlang receive expression works?

Tags: erlang, elixir

- Why receive expression is sometimes called selective receive?
- What is the "save queue"?
- How the after section works?

Comment: have a look at this question (and my answer :o): [what is the purpose to introduce a save queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747039/whats-the-purpose-to-introduce-save-queue-in-erlang-receive-statement)

Answer (score 3):

There is a special "save queue" involved in the procedure that when you first encounter the receive expression you may ignore its presence.

Optionally, there may be an after-section in the expression that complicates the procedure a little.

The receive expression is best explained with a flowchart:

```
receive
  pattern1 -> expressions1;
  pattern2 -> expressions2;
  pattern3 -> expressions3
after
  Time -> expressionsTimeout
end
```

[image: Erlang receive]

Answer (score 1):

> Why receive expression is sometimes called selective receive?

```
-module(my).
%-export([test/0, myand/2]).
-compile(export_all).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

start() ->
    spawn(my, go, []).

go() ->
    receive
        {xyz, X} ->
            io:format("I received X=~w~n", [X])
    end.
```

In the erlang shell:

```
1> c(my).
my.erl:3: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

2> Pid = my:start().                
<0.79.0>

3> Pid ! {hello, world}.
{hello,world}

4> Pid ! {xyz, 10}.     
I received X=10
{xyz,10}
```

Note how there was no output for the first message that was sent, but there was output for the second message that was sent.  The receive was selective: it did not receive all messages, it received only messages matching the specified pattern.

> What is the "save queue"?

```
-module(my).
%-export([test/0, myand/2]).
-compile(export_all).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

start() ->
    spawn(my, go, []).

go() ->
    receive
        {xyz, X} ->
            io:format("I received X=~w~n", [X])
    end,
    io:format("What happened to the message that didn't match?"),
    receive 
        Any ->
            io:format("It was saved rather than discarded.~n"),
            io:format("Here it is: ~w~n", [Any])
    end.
```

In the erlang shell:

```
1> c(my).               
my.erl:3: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported 
{ok,my}

2> Pid = my:start().    
<0.79.0>

3> Pid ! {hello, world}.
{hello,world}

4> Pid ! {xyz, 10}.     
I received X=10
What happened to the message that didn't match?{xyz,10}
It was saved rather than discarded.
Here it is: {hello,world}
```

> How the after section works?

```
-module(my).
%-export([test/0, myand/2]).
-compile(export_all).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

start() ->
    spawn(my, go, []).

go() ->
    receive
        {xyz, X} ->
            io:format("I received X=~w~n", [X])
    after 10000 ->
        io:format("I'm not going to wait all day for a match.  Bye.")
    end.
```

In the erlang shell:

```
1> c(my).           
my.erl:3: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported 
{ok,my}

2> Pid = my:start().
<0.79.0>

3> Pid ! {hello, world}.
{hello,world}
I'm not going to wait all day.  Bye.4>
```

Another example:

```
-module(my).
%-export([test/0, myand/2]).
-compile(export_all).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

sleep(X) ->
    receive
    after X * 1000 ->
        io:format("I just slept for ~w seconds.~n", [X])
    end.
```

In the erlang shell:

```
1> c(my).
my.erl:3: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported 
{ok,my}

2> my:sleep(5).                   
I just slept for 5 seconds.
ok
```