# Sequential method to concurrent method?

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to change this method from sequential to concurrent:

```
seq(Y, Z) ->
  P = Y+Z,
  Q = Z*Y,
  P/Q.
```

Here's what I have so far, I'm pretty confused right now so it probably doesn't make much sense.

```
P(Y, Z) -> Y+Z.
Q(Y, Z) -> Z*Y.

cc() ->
  receive
        {Y, Z} -> P(Y, Z)/Q(Y, Z)
  end.

run() ->
  pid = spawn(?MODULE, cc, []),
  pid ! {10, 12}
```

Comment: How would you write solution for this task in algorithm form?(I mean step by step)

Comment: assign workers that find P and Q concurrently then divide the result @Atomic_alarm

Comment: ok, so you need a)learn how spawn separate process for '+' and for '*' and b)how sent message from one process to another one, right?

Comment: @Atomic_alarm yes, got an assessment on this topic in 1.5 hours, care to gimme a hand?

Comment: @Atomic_alarm can't find any good resources online

Comment: I'll try to help you find a solution. First of all, do you check [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html)?

Comment: @Atomic_alarm how do I spawn 2 processes concurrently and then return both results to the same receive?

Comment: you don't need concurrent spawn you need concurrent evaluation. `receive` is just expression which check if there any message in mailbox. Here corresponding [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49306771/how-exactly-erlang-receive-expression-works).

Comment: what do you need for your third operation?

Comment: @Atomic_alarm [here](https://i.gyazo.com/e6624d51d9ecb441ffcb8779d5df1792.png) is a screenshot of what I have so far. It compiles but crashes when run.

Comment: you can put your code in some erlang compiler, for example, [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/erlang).

Comment: ok, since now you have excellent answer so I stop to try push you to right direction, but if you have any question free ping me. If single reason of this question is exam - remove your comments and I'll remove my , just for clean up history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p(Y, Z) -> Y+Z.
q(Y, Z) -> Z*Y.

cc(Y, Z) ->
    Self = self(),
    Pids = [spawn_link(fun() -> Self ! {self(), F(Y, Z)} end)
            || F <- [fun p/2, fun q/2]],
    [P, Q] = [receive {Pid, Result} -> Result end || Pid <- Pids],
    P/Q.
```

You can make it into "design pattern"

```
-module(cc).

-export([cc/2]).

-define(RUNCC_TIMEOUT, 5000).

-define(L(X), fun() -> X end).

runcc(Fs) ->
    runcc(Fs, ?RUNCC_TIMEOUT).

runcc(Fs, Timeout) ->
    Self = self(),
    Pids = [spawn_link(fun() -> Self ! {self(), F()} end) || F <- Fs],
    [receive {Pid, Result} -> Result after Timeout -> error(timeout) end
     || Pid <- Pids].

cc(Y, Z) ->
    [P, Q] = runcc([?L(Y+Z), ?L(Y*Z)]),
    P/Q.
```